# Delete duplicate keys with relation algebra

Tags: relational-theory, relational-algebra, relational-calculus

Hi I am new to databases and relational algebra. I was wondering if there is a way to remove the tuples from a table using relational algebra that have the same keys but different value.

e.g. I want to keep only [1, 5] and [4, 9] but remove everything else.

```
Key    | Value
-------|-------
 1     | 5
 2     | 6
 2     | 7
 2     | 8
 4     | 9
```

Thanks.

Comment: There are many relational algebras. They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give operator definitions & your reference for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many variants and extensions of relational algebra described in books. I assume that you have a group by operator, which is an extension of the classical relational algebra, and it is written as:

a<sub>1</sub>... a<sub>*n*</sub> γ f<sub>1</sub>...f<sub>*m*</sub>

where each a<sub>*i*</sub> is a grouping attribute, and f<sub>i</sub> is an aggregation function.

Using this operator, your query could be answered by the following expression (assuming that the name of your relation is R):

R ⨝ π<sub>Key</sub>(σ<sub>COUNT(*)=1</sub>(<sub>Key</sub> γ <sub>COUNT(*)</sub> (R)))

First we group by Key and keep only the groups with a unique value for it, and then we perform a natural join on R itself to maintain only the tuples with just one value of Key.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like the following (see the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f34ecd86695148daf248f23a9aec043f)):

Create and populate a table:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  key INTEGER NOT NULL,
  value INTEGER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES
(1, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (4, 9);
```

and then:

```
SELECT * FROM test;
```

Result:

```
key     value
  1         5
  2         6
  2         7
  2         8
  4         9
```

and then run the following SQL:

```
SELECT key, value
FROM test WHERE key IN
(
  SELECT key
  FROM test
  GROUP BY key
  HAVING COUNT(key) = 1
  ORDER BY key
);
```

Result:

```
key     value
  1         5
  4         9
```

Which is the desired result. I have used PostgreSQL - the Open Source database which I would recommend that you use to learn relational database principles - it has a very high level of standards compliance and is a great learning tool.

The inner loop of SQL

```
SELECT key
FROM test
GROUP BY key
HAVING COUNT(key) = 1
ORDER BY key
```

produces those `key`s which have a `COUNT` of only 1 (in this case, the integers 1 and 4) and then the outer loop selects the `value`s corresponding to those two integers (see the fiddle).

Comment: How would this be translated to relation algebra specifically GROUP BY and the HAVING count condition ?

Comment: My apologies - I thought that when you said `I am new to databases and relational algebra.` (RA), you meant more SQL than pure relational algebra *per se*. Now SQL doesn't claim (or even try) to be a perfect implementation of RA, but I did a quick search and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665635/algebra-relational-sql-group-by-sort-by-order-by) and also [here](https://www.inf.unibz.it/~artale/DB2/handout3.pdf) (p. 27). I hope this is helpful, but RA isn't an area of expertise of mine (studied many moons ago...). I'm open to suggestions as to how I could rewrite my answer!